# Let A be a square matrix so that AB = BA for every square matrix B of the same order. Prove that A is a diagonal matrix.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let A be a square matrix so that AB = BA for every square matrix B of the same order. Prove that A is a diagonal matrix.

I have no clue as to how to even start.

Answer (score 0):

As a baby example, let us do it in the case $2\times2$. Since $A$ is unknown let us denote:
$$A=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{array}} \right)$$
And $AB=BA$ for every $2\times 2$ matrix $B$ so let us take some particular easy matrices $B$, to see what they implies on $A$. Let us take these two matrices:
$$B_1=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&1\\
0&0
\end{array}} \right)~~B_2=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0\\
1&0
\end{array}} \right)$$
Then $AB_1=B_1A$ implies:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&a\\
0&c
\end{array}} \right)=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
c&d\\
0&0
\end{array}} \right)$$
So $c=0$ and $a=d$. Now $AB_2=B_2A$ implies:
$$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
b&0\\
d&0
\end{array}} \right)=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&0\\
a&b
\end{array}} \right)$$
So $b=0$ and $a=d$. With all this conditions our matrix is:
$$A=\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
a&0\\
0&a
\end{array}} \right)$$
which is a diagonal matrix. As homework you have two things to do:

- Check that this $A$ satisfy $AB=BA$ for every $2\times 2$ matrix $B$, which will finish the exercise.
- Generalize the result to $n\times n$ matrices using the same argument.

Both things are quite easy, and it shouldn't take you many time. Hope that helps you to understand the exercise.